# Create page template via functions.php?

Tags: php, functions, customization, filters, templates

I want to create a new selectable page template for users that will allow them to identify which pages on the site are "Service" pages (eg plumbing, gas fitting, etc). The template is an exact copy of page.php but includes some JSON LD (schema.org code) for "Service" pages on their website.

I really don't want a whole new servicepage.php file for this, that is just a carbon copy of page.php.

(How) Could I do this using only functions.php? Adding a new plugin is not currently an option.

Comment: "I want to create a new selectable page template" - it can be made selectable using the [`theme_page_templates` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/), but I posted this as a comment because I don't get the "I really don't want a whole new servicepage.php file". Or that the hook I mentioned requires a template file.

Comment: If servicepage.php is the same as page.php then there's no reason for it to be there as it will do exactly the same thing. If services are a custom post type then you should really create a template for that post type and keep all the content to a partial so that page.php and servicepage.php are minimal. single-POST_TYPE.php would be automatically used for any posts of that type so no need to manually select the template.

Comment: Hi Robert - I want to create a new page template that the user can select and when selected it will add some specific JSON LD (schema.org code). It is meant to the be the same as page.php, except with the added JSON. Does that make sense? I need some way for the user to indicate that it is a "Service" type page administratively...

Comment: For now I decided to do it via a template php file and `include` page.php, as mentioned here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-create-a-minimalist-clone-of-a-template-that-will-stay-up-to-date/ but still interested to do it with a file-less solution if one presents itself that I can manage. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous question, [Possible to create a "variant" page template that only contains differences and is therefore resilient to updates of original (ie page.php)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/387810/possible-to-create-a-variant-page-template-that-only-contains-differences-and), provided nicely more context to this question.

As you Sally CJ noted in the comments you use [theme_page_templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/) to add custom template to the template select list. To skip adding a separate file for the template, use [template_include](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter to select `page.php` as the actual template file. Target the template on the front end on [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) action with [is_page_template()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) conditional to add data printing function to `wp_head`.

For example like this,

```
function my_service_template_slug() {
    return 'my-service-template.php';
}

function my_service_template_name() {
    return __( 'My Service Template', 'my-textdomain' );
}

// Add custom template to the template list
add_filter(
    'theme_page_templates',
    function( $page_templates, $theme, $post ){
        $page_templates[my_service_template_slug()] = my_service_template_name();
        return $page_templates;
    },
    11,
    3
);

// Use default page.php as servcie template
add_filter(
    'template_include',
    function( $template ) {
        return my_service_template_slug() === $template ? 'page.php' : $template;
    },
    11,
    1
);

// Add data to service template head
add_action(
    'template_redirect',
    function(){
        if ( is_page_template( my_service_template_slug() ) ) {
            add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_service_template_head_data');
        }
    }
);

function my_service_template_head_data() {
    // print something
}
```

Comment: Thanks Antti for answering my question! However I can't quite follow. My main point was that I was hoping to avoid needing a separate php file (ie, my-service-template.php)... if it is necessary, then I guess I can just add a `template_include` page.php + my custom JSON code and be done with it - without needing to involve function.php at all? I hope that made sense... thanks.

Comment: @Drewdavid Yes, with the above code example you don't need to add a separate template file. But to make the "virtual" template appear in the template select list, you need to provide the related filter a file name even though the file doesn't exist in reality. This is what the first filter does in my example. Second filter is an explicit way of telling WP, which file to actually use for rendering the page when using the "virtual" template. I guess WP would figure this out by itself, based on template hierarchy, if doesn't find the custom template file, but I didn't double check this.

Comment: The `template_redirect` action is identifying pages using the "virtual" template so that you can add the required JSON LD only on those pages. The above code can be added to the `functions.php` file, to a custom plugin, or to one of those plugins that let you save php in the Dashboard. It just needs to go somewhere on your site to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Antti for your comments! I ended up using it as a simple plugin since I am including a couple data files so wanted a folder for them. So far it's working just perfectly and I'm learning something too haha. =)